# Can I use my pen tablet as a display and tablet for another computer?

Tags: remote-desktop, tablet, remote, wacom

I have an old Fujitsu Stylistic, a portable computer with a display and a pressure-sensitive Wacom-brand pen input. I would like to use this for art, however, I have found that the device is too old and slow to handle the art software I use.

In order to solve this problem, I am wondering: Is there some way I could use this tablet as a display and input device for my other computer?

Comment: Yes, by using a remote desktop system of some kind, such as [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/) - although that might be slow / laggy too, depending on how fast your network is.

Comment: @JonasCz I wasn't aware that there was any pressure-sensitivity support over VNC. I'll have to give this a try later today, thank you.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you needed pressure sensitivity support - there [are ways to do that though](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/how-can-i-turn-my-old-tablet-pc-into-a-cintiq-like-pen-tablet) if you can get it to work.